# How to find variable declare is not use in the class in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

In Roslyn how do I find out if a private member variable is not used in class?

I have task that to comment any unused private variables. For example:

```
class Test
{
   private int I;// if it's not use then i need to comment it out.
}
```

Comment: So you want to comment all variable declarations which: 1. Are not initialized in the declaring location? 2. Are not assigned inside the the declaring type?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici - I want to comments variable which are not use means unuse variable in class.

Comment: Have you thought what would happen if the variable would be used by other classes? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I just want to comment local variable in class not global variable.

Comment: I have added example in my question.

Comment: By "local" you mean a non-public field? The term "local" is generally reserved for variables within method bodies.

Comment: Yes local means non-public either in class or in Method.

Comment: Are you looking for private, protected and internal members then, or just private? If it's protected and internal, then, of course they could be initialised from outside the class.

Comment: Also, are you looking for those that are not initialised upon declaration, or not used at all within the class?

Comment: Looking for only private variables and not use at all in the class, thanks for all questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create semantic model and pass it to the Rewriter class constructor in Main method.

```
SemanticModel sm = Compilation.Create("StylecopImplementor")
    .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("mscorlib"))
    .AddSyntaxTrees(fileTree).GetSemanticModel(fileTree);

Rewriter syntaxwr = new Rewriter(sm);
```

I expose my semantic model to my Rewritter class.

```
class Rewriter : SyntaxRewriter
{
    SemanticModel model { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Diagnostic> diagonists;

    public Rewriter(SemanticModel pModel)
    {
        model = pModel;             
        diagonists = pModel.GetDiagnostics();
    }
}
```

Then I use below code in VisitVariableDeclaration.

```
if (diagonists.Count() > 0)
{
    var diagitems = diagonists.Where(d => d.Info.MessageIdentifier.ToString().Equals("CS0168")).ToList();

    if (diagitems != null)
    {
        var ditem = diagitems.Where(d => d.Location.GetLineSpan(false).StartLinePosition.Line == node.GetLocation().GetLineSpan(false).StartLinePosition.Line).FirstOrDefault();

        if (ditem != null)
        {
            node = node.WithLeadingTrivia(Syntax.ParseTrailingTrivia("//"));                            
        }
    }
}

return base.VisitVariableDeclaration(node);
```

It will comment your variable declaration in your .cs file if it's not in use.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler (as seen in VS.NET) will certainly issue a warning, you can get warnings from Roslyn too (found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/11/23/using-the-roslyn-symbol-api.aspx)).

For deeper code analysis I'd suggest using more advanced tool, for example [Phoenix](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/collaboration/focus/cs/phoenix.aspx) compiler.

Comment: Thanks for this I use warning to get this implements.